# QGIS 3D - no terrain altitude binding

Tags: qgis, 3d, 3d-map

I have tested with point and polygon layer. I get no terrain altitude binding.  I use for the project and for the layer crs WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N (32632). Screenshot example with point layer, cylinder. I use SRTM1 data for the terrain.
Also tested without success: altitude clamping absolute and relative.

What could I do better to get a correct result? Or is this a bug within QGIS?

QGIS 3.10.5, Windows 10
[image]

This is want I want (black cylinders):
[image]

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: I have edited my question above with a new screenshot. All cylinders should stand completely on the mountain surface, not underneath.

Comment: Some thing strange for me with your DEM settings. Why do you have that vertical side? Did you set something in the 3D view properties of the DEM? The DEM should have no width.

Comment: I use within den 3D settings "skirt height" to hide cracks. If this value is "0" the problem with the objects are the same.
Read there: https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2018/03/01/working-with-qgis-3d-part-1/

Comment: I cannot reproduce your situation. Can you try the same on a fresh QGIS installation or create a new user profile to have the default settings? I suppose some settings have been changed.

Comment: I can reproduce the fault. New project. Same problem. Only change within the 3D settings is the vertical size, nothing more.
You get a good result?
Tomorrow a try a new QGIS installation.

Comment: Now I have this projekt to test a point layer / zylinders:
https://public.cloudmergin.com/projects/saber/luxembourg/tree
Result: all OK!
Now I must find my fault setting/s. It could be the crs. I'm working on it.....

Comment: OK. I think the reason for my problem is the use of SRTM data from USGS. What can I do to use this data correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have found a solution:

1. I have reprojected the srtm1 raster with: 
   raster - projections - warp(reproject) /
   target crs: in my case: WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N

(not a solution: change the raster layer to this crs)

2. Edit the point layer with my zylinder:
   3D: I have changed the translation "y" value (in my case "200")

Result:
The same zylinder-height, but not the same total-height (terrain-height  +  zylinder-height) within the terrain. And no zylinder "under" the terrain.
Example:
[image]