# Overlaying Aviation Airspace Boundaries in QGIS 3D Map View

Tags: qgis-3

I'm a new user of QGIS 3.12.3 Bucuresti (and GIS in general).

I have loaded OS Terrain 50, overlaid with a mix of Google Satellite and OpenStreetMap which produces a 3D Map view that I am very happy with.

However, on trying to load obstructions such as masts, church spires etc. represented by columns up to the altitude (above MSL/Geoid) and protection surfaces represented by polygons in 3D space the obstructions and surfaces just appear to be draped over the surface of the terrain mapping with no elevation.

I started with obstruction data in CSV format, latitude, longitude and elevation which produced circles on the map surface.  Am I missing something simple here please?

Comment: I think this: There are problems with 3D, for example often crashes. I hope the programmers can solve the most relevant problems as soon as possible. With the stable version 3.10.6 I have less problems than with the version 3.12.3. Maybe this could also helps you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361191/qgis-3d-no-terrain-altitude-binding/361914#361914 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363299/qgis-3d-no-terrain-altitude-binding-for-polygons-buildings/363362#363362